# Prevent Cross Domain Script Included- Self XSS in asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I tried suggested ways to prevent Cross Domain Script Included- Self XSS in dot net core 5.0 but still I am not able to fix that.

The issue I am facing is when someone comes to our site and run the Cross Domain Script (ex: $.getScript("https://test.int.domain.in/selfxss.js")) in browser console its getting executed and getting alert. so that hackers can easily inject malicious data into server through script.

but its not resolved.
and I referred some blogs including MS docs and done the code changes (including Antixss)  but it didn't help me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

please let me know what I can do for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
             context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block"); 
            await next();
        });
```

Comment: Look into adding a `Content-Security-Policy` header with as strict a policy as possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP